# Boundary Timers do not work in Activiti 6

Tags: java, activiti, business-process-management

I use boundary timer, and it does not work. If there are no elements after the timer, the process goes on this sequenceflow. If there is a service task after the timer, the process goes on the normal path. Here is a part of my bpm scheme:
[image]

I use Spring 5 for creating of the beans for Activiti. Here is the example of my bean configuration class:

```
     @Bean
SpringProcessEngineConfiguration processEngineConfiguration(@Qualifier("dataSourceForActiviti") DataSource dataSourceForActiviti,
                                                            @Qualifier("transactionManagerForActiviti") PlatformTransactionManager transactionManagerForActiviti) {
    SpringProcessEngineConfiguration processEngineConfiguration = new SpringProcessEngineConfiguration();
    processEngineConfiguration.setTransactionManager(transactionManagerForActiviti);

    processEngineConfiguration.setDataSource(dataSourceForActiviti)
            .setDatabaseSchemaUpdate(ProcessEngineConfiguration.DB_SCHEMA_UPDATE_TRUE)
            .setAsyncExecutorActivate(true)
    ;

    processEngineConfiguration.setDeploymentResources(new Resource[]{
            new ClassPathResource("bpm/LicensingProcess.bpmn20.xml"),
            new ClassPathResource("bpm/ReissuanceLicenseProcess.bpmn20.xml"),
            new ClassPathResource("bpm/IssueOfDuplicateProcess.bpmn20.xml"),
            new ClassPathResource("bpm/IssuanceOfCopyProcess.bpmn20.xml"),
            new ClassPathResource("bpm/TerminationOfLicenseProcess.bpmn20.xml"),
            new ClassPathResource("bpm/ExtractFromRegisterOfLicensesProcess.bpmn20.xml")
    });


    return processEngineConfiguration;
}

@Bean
ProcessEngineFactoryBean processEngineFactoryBean(SpringProcessEngineConfiguration processEngineConfiguration) {
    ProcessEngineFactoryBean processEngineFactoryBean = new ProcessEngineFactoryBean();
    processEngineFactoryBean.setProcessEngineConfiguration(processEngineConfiguration);
    return processEngineFactoryBean;
}

@Bean
RepositoryService repositoryService(ProcessEngineFactoryBean processEngineFactoryBean) throws Exception {
    return processEngineFactoryBean.getObject().getRepositoryService();
}

@Bean
RuntimeService runtimeService(ProcessEngineFactoryBean processEngineFactoryBean) throws Exception {
    return processEngineFactoryBean.getObject().getRuntimeService();
}

@Bean
TaskService taskService(ProcessEngineFactoryBean processEngineFactoryBean) throws Exception {
    return processEngineFactoryBean.getObject().getTaskService();
}
```

I tried to comment and uncomment the line `setAsyncExecutorActivate(true)`, and there was no difference. At the same time, if you put the timer as a separate unit, everything works.

PS I have just found the such solution (it is being added to the definition of the '`ProcessEngineConfiguration`' bean):

```
// Async Job Executor
final DefaultAsyncJobExecutor asyncExecutor = new DefaultAsyncJobExecutor();
asyncExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(50);
asyncExecutor.setQueueSize(100);
processEngineConfiguration.setAsyncExecutor(asyncExecutor);
```

But it also did not help me. Although without it the `asyncJobExecutor` was `null`.

PSS At the same time, a similar scheme works great in the Activiti Modeler. And I can not understand why it works there and does not work for me

PSSS I have written a simple application on the `Swing` and without `Spring`. I used the `StandaloneProcessEngineConfiguration` class and I did not use the `SpringProcessEngineConfiguration` and `ProcessEngineFactoryBean` classes. And it works but if i put the service task or script task after `boundary timer` (not timer event as a separate element), it does works. It writes that it cannot find an engine for groovy (for `script task`), and it writes that it cannot instantiate a specified class (for `service task`). If there is an `user task` after `boundary timer`, it works.

Comment: This site is rather English only site, so diagrams in Cyrylic as kind of uselss for most of participant here.

Comment: @Antoniossss Yes, but the writings on the blocks are not so important. Although i agree that it would be more readable and clearer if the inscriptions were in English. But you can look at the icons on the blocks

Comment: Well, I have changed the picture